# Which is better to catch all exceptions except given types: catch and rethrow or catch when?

Tags: c#, exception

If I wanted to catch all exceptions except for given types, and those specific types would be re-thrown to be caught in a higher context, would it be better to do:

```
try
{
    //Code that might throw an exception
}
//Catch exceptions to be handled in this context
catch (Exception ex) when (!IsExcludedException(ex))
{
    //Handle leftover exceptions
}
```

Or would it be better to do:

```
try
{
    //Code that might throw an exception
}
catch (SpecificException)
{
    throw;
}
//Catch exceptions to be handled in this context
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Handle leftover exceptions
}
```

Or does it not really matter? Is there a better way?

Comment: You'll never know what exceptions occur and you'll not be able to handle them. What about an OutOfMemoryException?

Comment: That seems pretty unusual.  Usually you do the opposite.  But you're saying `I know about this error, but I can't handle it.  But I can handle anything else!`

Comment: To give context, in this case I have a static method in a helper class that is handling a file processing task, and if that throws a specific type of exception I want it to be caught by the code that calls the method so it can be displayed to the user. In all other cases I want to handle the exception within the helper class.

Comment: Clarification: by "I want to" I mean "the project requirements state I should". Additionally, the example is simplified, in reality I'm catching the exceptions I'd expect to be thrown and handling them individually, with a `catch (Exception ex)` as a fallback.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The second way is definitely cleaner to analyse and it's what I see the most. The specific catch happens first and doesn't trigger the generic one, but you still have a fallback if you didn't implement a specific one. Also, for handling more than one specific exception you'd need more `!(ex is SpecificException)` checks as well.

Comment: You see that the most because the other way is very new. People could not implement it for a long time

Comment: Still, you'd need to do `when (!(ex is OneSpecificException || ex is OtherSpecificException || ex is SomeOtherSpecificException)`

Comment: @Qrchack That could easily be wrapped into a method which, if named properly, would be just as clear.